# Is it bad to use TFVC as an artifact repository for full releases?

Tags: tfs, version-control, nexus, artifactory, tfvc

I work for a company where we store the build outputs (artifacts, each from varying technologies) from a large amount of different applications into TFVC, then from our repository to our environment servers. I have been investigating artifact repositories to get us off of using TFVC for these outputs. While gathering requirements I was questioned why I was looking into alternatives. Reading the documentation of [TFVC](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/overview) I found this:

> You can use Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) to scale from small to large projects, and by using server workspaces, you can scale up to very large codebases with millions of files per branch and large binary files.

I can't honestly answer the question why we should use an  artifact repository over TFVC. It's named Team Foundation Server **Version Control**, not **Source Control**. Part of our requirement is versioning and backups. Once we're fully automated we won't have a requirement for these repositories, however, as it stands, we need some form of versioned repository for our artifacts. 
So my questions are:

- Is it bad to use TFVC for storing a large amount of binary files
  (build outputs)?
- Why would I want to use an artifact repository over TFVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you copy build output to drop/share folders. This will store the build output **outside of version control** but in the tfs server database.

As for is it bad to use TFVC for storing a large amount of binary files (build outputs). Generally speaking, regardless good or bad, it's according to your needs.

On TFS2012, you can still copy the build outputs to the source control folder. So this is definitely support in TFVC.
[image]

Some limitations: If you put the build output into source control, it also meant that you clogged up your version control repository with files and sometimes big files. When files are added to a versioned repository there are a lot of computing power used to figure out versions and deltas and other need things, but for a drop folder we don’t need those.

Worse when you want to remove old stuff you need to call a “**destroy**” command to be sure that you don’t leave all of those files taking up space forever.

Also take a look at this blog: [New un-versioned repository in TFS 2012](https://nkdagility.com/new-un-versioned-repository-in-tfs-2012/)

Answer (score 2):

Other than space/repository bloat concerns, the key reason is versioning. If you create (for example) NuGet packages for your binaries, you can safely reference different versions for different applications, and not have to worry about changes introducing issues (be they bugs or compilation errors) in applications that haven't been tested against the latest version of the dependency. As an example:

You have DependencyFoo that you turn into a NuGet package.

Application A references version 1.0.

Application B references version 1.0.

In order to support Application A, you make some changes to your DependencyFoo package. You can then update the version referenced by Application A **without impacting Application B at all**.

Beyond that, if you ever decide to transition to Git from TFVC, Git does not handle binaries well, and as a matter of course should never be included in version control.